# Save curl download statistics / log

Tags: file, logging, curl, command-line, statistics

I'm reading a stream with curl and grep some highlights.

```
curl url | grep desired_key_word
```

I've noticed that curl is providing me some nice download statistics such as:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 10.9M    0 10.9M    0     0  1008k      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:-- 1092k
```

How can I save those statistics e.g. every second in a file?

I found this: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2002-11/0115.html however it was not able to abstract it to my problem.

```
curl -n agent.mtconnect.org/sample\?interval=0 -o xml_stream.log 2>> dl.log
```

The dl.log should have the statistics included, however is does not work.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the unabstracted version.

`curl -s -S -n http://speedtest.fremont.linode.com/100MB-fremont.bin -o /dev/null -w "%{time_total},%{size_download},%{speed_download}\n" >> stats.log`

Comment: +1 Wow. This is not only the exact command I was looking for, but also the exact file I was hoping to perform a download test on. Creepy.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same exact need for checking a month's worth of internet speed.

Comment: In my testing, this could hang forever if e.g. the network went down. So I added `--max-time 600`. I also updated the output format to add `%{errormsg}`.

Answer (score 0):

Only the stdout get redirected by the -o flag.

For the -o flag the man page states:

```
-o/--output <file>
          Write output to <file> instead of stdout...
```

If you want stderr, you need something like this:

```
curl -n agent.mtconnect.org/sample\?interval=0 >> xml_stream.log 2>> dl.log
```